# Why scope resolution necessary for struct define inside a class when returning as value?

Tags: c++, class, scope

I have a singly linked list implementation as shown below:

**Header**

```
class SinglyLinkedList
{
  struct Node
  {
    Node * _pNext;
    int    _data;
  };

public:

  Node * SomeFun(Node * ip1, Node * ip2);  
  // Some more methods here
};
```

Now when implementing one of the methods of this class

**CPP**

```
Node * SinglyLinkedList::SomeFun(Node * ip1, Node * ip2)
{
  //Some code and return
}
```

The strange behavior I am not understanding is that when compiling, the compiler
refuses to recognize the type "Node" in the return type unless I specify it as 
***SinglyLinkedList::Node***. But the same type for function arguments is recognized
without specifying it explicitly.. Ideally I felt that in both cases there should be
no need for this explicit specifying because Node is defined in the same class.
Can anyone throw some light on this?

Comment: Well, unfortunately the explanation is "that's the rule". Since technically `SinglyLinkedList::` signals the scope's start, you can't use `Node` before that without qualifying it.

Comment: `Ideally I felt that in both cases there should be no need for this explicit specifying because Node is defined in the same class.` - this is not true, there can be a Node struct outside the class and `Node * SinglyLinkedList::SomeFun` might use just that class instead of internal one.

Comment: This is one reason for the new C++11 return notation: `auto SinglyLinkedList::SomeFun(...) -> Node*`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SinglyLinkedList::Node * SinglyLinkedList::SomeFun
```

Here, you are not in class-scope. But in parameters clause, or in function you are IN class-scope, so you shouln't qualify, that `Node` is from class `SinglyLinkedList`, since compiler already knows that.

n3376 3.3.7/1

> The following rules describe the scope of names declared in classes.
>
> **The potential scope of a declaration** that extends to or past the end of a class definition **also ex-
> tends to the regions defined by its member definitions**, even if the members are defined lexically
> outside the class (this includes static data member definitions, nested class definitions, **member func-
> tion definitions (including the member function body and any portion of the declarator part of such
> definitions which follows the declarator-id, including a parameter-declaration-clause and any default
> arguments**

Answer (score 3):

Adding to ForEveR's answer, this issue is solved in C++11 using trailing return clauses.

```
// Regular return style
SinglyLinkedList::Node* SinglyLinkedList::SomeFun(Node * ip1, Node * ip2) { ... }

// Trailing return style
auto SinglyLinkedList::SomeFun(Node * ip1, Node * ip2) -> Node * { ... }
```

In the regular style, you have *not yet* entered class scope (it only begins after the qualified name of the method has ended).

In the trailing return style however, the return type is in the class scope (like the arguments) and therefore the qualification not necessary.