# When implementing a function, why scope resolution operator is needed in return value, but not in argument?

Tags: c++

While I am splitting the class definition and implemention from one source file to header+implememtation, I got a problem.

Class definition (part of), BinarySearchTree.hpp,

```
class BinarySearchTree
{
    public:
        const int & findMin() const;
    private:
        struct BinaryNode
        {
            int element;
            BinaryNode* left_p;
            BinaryNode* right_p;
        }
        BinaryNode* root_p;
        BinaryNode* findMin(BinaryNode* tree_p) const;
};
```

Class implementation (part), BinarySearchTree.cpp:

```
#include "BinarySearchTree.hpp"

const int & BinarySearchTree::findMin() const
{
    return findMin(root_p)->element;
}

BinarySearchTree::BinaryNode* BinarySearchTree::findMin(BinaryNode* tree_p) const
{
    if (tree_p == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
            
    if (tree_p->left_p == nullptr)
        return tree_p; 
            
    return findMin(tree_p->left_p);
}
```

These codes can be compiled without problem. I am using g++ 8.3.0 on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B running Linux. Command line:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g *.cpp -o test.out
```

If I removed BinarySearchTree:: from the return value of function implementation, compiler will complain about 'BinaryNode' does not name a type. However, it has come to my attention that I did not put "BinarySearchTree::" in the argument of the function, nor in any other function implementation where 'BinaryNode' is present.

My question is, why the scope solution is exactly needed in return value (and function name), but not anywhere else?

Comment: If you are defining it inside the class, you already are IN the scope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why scope resolution necessary for struct define inside a class when returning as value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953990/why-scope-resolution-necessary-for-struct-define-inside-a-class-when-returning-a)

Comment: What you are describing is called [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup).  When you name something, like `BinaryNode`, the compiler has to lookup where that name is defined.  And while **inside** `class BinarySearchTree`, that class' symbols will be checked.